# Matter Modelers! Try to get these hats!

Tags: discussion, participation, voting, winter-bash

It's that time of the year again, and I've picked out the hats that I think would be most valuable to our site and community if as many people as possible were to try to get them!

#### Gem detector

[image: Gem detector]

Cast 50 upvotes on questions that stay open

---

#### Plus 44

[image: Plus 44]

Write a good answer to a good question

---

#### Rep hunter

[image: Rep hunter]

Write 10 good answers in one day

---

#### Hi5

[image: Hi5]

Have five of your answers accepted in one day

---

#### Tenacious

[image: Tenacious]

Write a good self-answer to an old question

---

Thank you to all the Matter Modelers who have voted so far!

[image]

Comment: I see you're hoping to get the Soapbox hat?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison I already got it long ago! Maybe not on this particular site.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison you're not going for defender of the unicorn this time?